How can I wait for child controls to exist when programmatically switching tabs?
I am building a wizard-like detail view popup for handling a multi-step workflow. I have created the necessary layout in Model.xafml, and am able to display and click between tabs. But I want to add Next/Previous buttons to the view, and programmatically switch between tabs. The issue I am having is that I need to interact with a child listview on the newly active tab. But the list view doesn't exist yet.
I've tried using a ManualResetEvent, to wait for the child view to get created. But then it blocks and the view doesn't get created. So I need to create some sort of callback or event that I can trigger when on the new tab, and the controls are created.
I'm at a bit of a loss how to set this up, and even how to describe what I need to do. How do I wait for the new tab to finish loading?
    public void Next_Clicked() {
        var index = ++tabModel.ActiveTabIndex;
        if (index == 1)
        {
            var retries = 0;

            // NOTE: attempted to wait for PoliciesFrame to exist
            while (!PoliciesListViewCreated.WaitOne(1000) && retries++ < 5)
            {
            }

            // NOTE: this line fails because PoliciesFrame is null  
            var linkUnlinkController = PoliciesFrame.GetController<LinkUnlinkController>();
            var window = Frame.GetController<WindowController>().Window;
    
            // display the link popup automatically.
            linkUnlinkController.LinkAction.DoExecute(window);
        }
    }

    protected override void CustomizeWindowPopup(object sender,     CustomizePopupWindowParamsEventArgs e)
    {
        base.CustomizeWindowPopup(sender, e);
        DetailView.CustomizeViewItemControl<ListPropertyEditor>(this,             ChildPropertyEditor, nameof(Transaction.Policies));
    }

    private void ChildPropertyEditor(ListPropertyEditor listPropertyEditor)
    {
        PoliciesListView = listPropertyEditor.ListView;
        PoliciesFrame = listPropertyEditor.Frame;
        PoliciesListView.SelectionChanged += NestedListView_SelectionChanged;

        // NOTE: this is not working. How to notify when ready?
        PoliciesListViewCreated.Set();
    }


